# How to find which package imported a given function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working on a trading system, I can write code in its strategy editor, and call some trading functions which doesn't require being imported explictly.
Now, I want to put the logic in a different package, so I need to figure out the package of those functions.

Do you know how to find the package to which a function belongs to?

Comment: Perhaps `print(fn.__module__)` where `fn` is the name of the function in question.

Comment: @Robᵩ doesn't work in my case, it prints `__main__`. Maybe I should create a proxy class and pass its instance to my package.

Comment: What about `import inspect; print(inspect.getmodule(fn))` ?

Comment: how about tools like `grep` to search string in files? ie. `grep function_name **.py` to search function_name in all py files in all subfolders.

Comment: @Antespo It still shows `__main__`. I give up now.